# How do I achieve full screen with a Fragment?

Tags: android, compatibility, android-fragments

I'm using the [compatibility library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) in an app I'm writing, so I can provide support back to Android 2.1 and use `Fragments`. I've got one `Activity` in my application that is in charge of displaying my Fragments. One Fragment plays video, so I want this particular Fragment to take up the entire screen. I have tried the following so far, which has not worked in achieving my goal:

```
getActionbar().hide();
```

Throws a No Such Method error, I'm guessing because I'm running the app on a Pre-Honeycomb device.

I have also tried calling:

```
getActivity().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

which crashes with the following:

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
```

I'm guessing that this is meant to be called when loading an Activity, not a Fragment.

Comment: First of all, if it was copied from file editor, it couldn't work - It should be getActionBar().hide(); (Capital B) instead of getActionbar().hide();

Answer (score 1):

The error speaks for itself. You gotta put the requestfeature line before calling setContentView.

Can you specify manifest like this and see if it is working for you?

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
```

I believe there is theme for fullscreen too.

Comment: If only it were that simple. There's no setContentView method in a Fragment. I tried calling it in onCreateView just before inflating and passing back my View, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: I don't want to remove the titlebar for the entire application, only a single Fragment.

Comment: @ChristopherPerry: Then apply the theme to the `<activity>` that hosts the fragment in question.